# How can I force a rebuild of a PHONY target more than once in the same makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have an application where I need to create groups of targets, where a given target may appear in more than one group as a dependency.  If multiple groups containing a common target are built in the same call to make, I want the common pre-requisite to be re-built *each time* and not just once for all groups.

For example:

```
   # Makefile.test_group_overrides

   GROUPS=group1 group2
   
   all: $(GROUPS)
   
   one:
           @echo $@ is $(NUM)
   
   two:
           @echo $@ is $(NUM)
   
   three:
           @echo $@ is $(NUM)
   
   group1: NUM=2
   group1: one two
   
   group2: NUM=3
   group2: two three
```

If I execute:

```
$ make -f Makefile.test_group_overrides group1
one is 2
two is 2
   
$ make -f Makefile.test_group_overrides group2
two is 3
three is 3
```

This is what I expect for each of the group targets executed independently.

However, if I try to build *both* groups in the same call to make like so:

```
$ make -f Makefile.test_group_overrides all
one is 2
two is 2
three is 3
```

It would appear that Make registers that it has already made target 'two' for group1 and so does not rebuild 'two' as a dependency for group2.

I've tried variations to force 'two' to be rebuilt using a .PHONY/FORCE target combination and the -B switch but haven't had any luck.

Is there a solution?  If possible, I would prefer not to create temporary files to solve.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

> If multiple groups containing a common target are built in the same call to make, I want the common pre-requisite to be re-built each time and not just once for all groups.

There is no way to accomplish this with any `make` implementation I know.  It is a fundamental characteristic of `make`'s design that each target is built at most once.  Phony targets are no exception.

If in fact you have targets that are built differently when associated with one group than they are when associated with a different group, then you are already straining `make`'s build model.  You ought in that case to split the targets into separate ones for each group, because that's really what you have anyway.  If you need the target built both ways, then that's a confirmation that you really do have different targets that you're trying to model as one.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!